# Toggle Flashlight with react-native (expo)

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I am trying  to toggle the flaslight from my react-native export app.
This [Plugin](https://github.com/ludo/react-native-torch) does not work since I am using expo.

The flashMode property of the [Expo Camera Component](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/camera/#flashmode) allows me to toggle the flash while taking a photo.

Is there a way to toggle the flashlight in another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into this same problem with `expo`. What I did was expo ejected and then used this library to toggle the flash light (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-torch). Then everything worked as it should

Comment: This is the library I linked in my question. I am trying to add it right now but I got some errors. Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1):

**This solves the problem of using torch while scanning QRCode/BarCode in React Native (Expo) Project**

```
<Camera 
    flashMode={Camera.Constants.FlashMode.torch}
    barCodeScannerSettings={{
    barCodeTypes:[BarCodeScanner.Constants.BarCodeType.qr]
    }}
    onBarCodeScanned={handleBarCodeScanned}
    />
```

**Preview**

| [image] |
| --- |

Comment: Hi, This looks pretty cool! Is there any chance for a full code? :D

Answer (score 1):

This work's for me:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Button, StyleSheet, View } from "react-native";

import { Camera } from "expo-camera";

const FLASH_MODE = {
  "on": 2,
  "off": 1
}

export default function App() {
  const [flashMode, setFlashMode] = useState(FLASH_MODE.off);
  const [permission, requestPermission] = Camera.useCameraPermissions();

  if (!permission) {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Button title="Permitir acceso a la cámara" onPress={requestPermission} />
      </View>
    )
  }

  const toggleFlashMode = () => {
    setFlashMode(flashMode === FLASH_MODE.on ? FLASH_MODE.off : FLASH_MODE.on)
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Button title="Cambiar flash" onPress={toggleFlashMode} />
      <Camera style={styles.camera} flashMode={flashMode} />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: "red",
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    width: "100vw",
    height: "100%"
  },

  camera: {
    width: 300,
    height: 300
  }
})
```

Comment: Works perfectly. If you only need the Flashlight, hide the Camera view in the styles.

```sh 

camera: {
  width: 300,
  height: 300,
  display: 'none',
},
```